# SharePoint 2013 Get user Groups

Tags: 2013, javascript, permissions

I am trying to do the following :

I got a js file here http://pastebin.com/g3Xtt96x

i want to change the part:

```
var whereStr = "";
if (!banderUtil.str.isNull(infoObj.listwhereclausefieldname) && !banderUtil.str.isNull(infoObj.listwhereclausefieldvalue)) 
    {
    whereStr = '
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="' + infoObj.listwhereclausefieldname + '"></FieldRef>
                <Value Type="Text">' + infoObj.listwhereclausefieldvalue + '</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>';
    }
```

to

```
var whereStr = "";
if (!banderUtil.str.isNull(infoObj.listwhereclausefieldname)) 
    {
    whereStr = '
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="' + infoObj.listwhereclausefieldname + '"></FieldRef>
                <Value Type="Text">' + "get current user group names" + '</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>';
    }
```

I couldnt get it to work i tried a lot of functions.

Comment: have you tried to add in a console.log in the if clause and check if it goes into the function?

Comment: i am sorry Patrick but my knowledge in sharepoint is limited i know what your trying to say but i cant write it for everyone wondering what app i am using http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5858 before we want to buy it i would like this to work

Comment: Patrick means you should use the Browser JS debugging tools to see where your code goes wrong, this has nothing to do with SharePoint: https://www.google.nl/search?q=f12+developer+tools+debugging

Answer (score 1):

I made another way to get te user and the group:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getCurrentUser();
});
function getCurrentUserGroupColl(UserID)
 {
  $.ajax
  ({
  url: "/sites/dialogo/_api/web/GetUserById("+UserID+")/Groups",
  type: "GET",
  headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose","X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() },
  dataType: "json",
  async: true,
   success: function(data){
      /* get all group's title of current user. */
      var results = data.d.results;
      for(var i=0; i< results.length; i++)
      {
            console.log(results[i].Title);
            var gp = results[i].Title;
            if(gp =="MyDefinedGroup")
            {
                //Do something
            }


      }
  }
  });
}
function getCurrentUser()
{
 $.ajax
  ({
  url: "/sites/dialogo/_api/web/Currentuser",
  type: "GET",
  headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose","X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() },
  dataType: "json",
  async: true,
  success: function(data){
    getCurrentUserGroupColl(data.d.Id)
  }
  });
}
```

*

> Im using sharepoint online (2013)

*